# Sitecore Web Item API 404

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.2

I have upgraded a Sitecore to SC7.2. When I open the media browser I can't explore the media items because I am getting a 404 from the Web Item API. The configs seem correct but I am wondering if files/items didn't get installed.

The URL being requested is:

http://{domain}/-/item/v1/sitecore/shell?sc_itemid=%7B3D6658D8-A0BF-4E75-B3E2-D050FABCF4E1%7D&scope=c&sc_database=master&language=en&fields=__Hidden

Has anyone seen this before? Anyone know how I can check if the Web Item Api was installed correctly?

Comment: Do the media items render on the front end? Know there's some funnies with media items when you upgrade to 7.2. - http://getfishtank.ca/blog/sitecore-7-2-upgrade-encoding-media-library-item-names

Comment: Do you have any custom Web API going on in the solution? I had the same issue your describing because I hijacked the routing

Comment: Media renders ok and we don't have any custom WEB API

Comment: Anything in the logs ?

Answer (score 1):

In order to check whether Item Web API is enabled or not.

1) Download [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

2) Enter Query: http://sc8/-/item/v1/?scope=c&sc_database=master&query=/sitecore/content

*[Note: sc8 will be replaced by your sitecore instance name]*

3) If you have enabled Standard Security in Sitecore Item Web API -- Enter Login Credentials and Click Execute.[image]

You will get the JSON response:
[image]

If you are getting the JSON response -- Your Sitecore Item Web API is enabled.

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by a custom site resolver in the HttpBeginRequest pipeline that had been added as part of support fix.